# Parse parts from multiple XML files into one XML file

Tags: xml, bash, shell, scripting

I have 3 .xml files and i need to extract multiple parts from each 
    one:

Sample1.xml contains:

```
   Name = name_1_version1_abc_123
   Type = body_size_number
   Version = version number
```

Sample2.xml contains:

```
   Date= date used
   Modified= modified time
   Version = version number
```

Sample3.xml contains:

```
   items= Item_number_1
   Type = Used for
   Version = version number
```

Each of these have multiple lines I just want these three lines from each file sent to an xml file. Every time I run the script the values will be different, so how would I receive the changed values every time I run this script in another file? Let me know if you need more information, I am running Linux.

Comment: I can't see an XML file. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML

Comment: update your question with a valid xml content for each crucial file. Also, post the expected result